# Built in function of converting string into array in php

Tags: php, arrays, string

I am consuming web-api from other site and it returns value like and is in string format-

```
[[["I eat rice","I ate rice","I am eating rice"] .... ]]
```

I am thinking about convert it in to an array or object(json)... is there any way to convert it using php bulitin function...

Comment: JSON is not object, it's text. The string you get from the API is JSON. Read about [`json_decode()`]php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use the `json_decode` function.

```
$string = '[[["I eat rice","I ate rice","I am eating rice"]]]';
$array = json_decode($string);
var_dump($array);
```

Which will be a multidimensional array:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "I eat rice"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "I ate rice"
      [2]=>
      string(16) "I am eating rice"
    }
  }
}
```